# unix - run a command as another user

Tags: unix, sudo

I am a newbie to Unix. I am trying to run a shell script and command as another user.

For example:
I am logged in as user1 and want to execute a script as user2. I dont want the password prompt and I want it to be auto-entered. I am aware of the public key authentication but I am trying to find if there is something like:

```
sudo -u user2 script.sh
```

I am trying to cron this, so I dont want the password prompt. I want it to be handled in the sudo command itself.

please help

Comment: I'll never understand this 'off topic' thing on Stack Overflow - it often strikes me that it's used by people who don't know the technology in the question or don't understand the question itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can add NOPASSWD option to `/etc/sudoers` file.
But may be it is not a good for you for security reasons.

```
user    user2 = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

Another option that you have: use `sudo`, but run it not directly from some script, but using `pexpect` or `expect`, that will enter the password for you. That is also may be not ideal from security point of view, because you need to save the password in the script.

With `expect` you can do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set password "megapassword"
spawn /bin/sudo -u user1 /usr/local/bin/script.sh
expect "password for user:"
send "$password\r"
expect eof
```

Don't forget to set 500 permission on that file.

With `pexpect` (that is a python module) this will look like:

```
import pexpect
password = "megapassword"
p = pexpect.spawn("sudo -u user1 /usr/local/bin/script.sh")
i = p.expect([".ssword:*", pexpect.EOF])
p.sendline(password)
```

If you run the command in `cron` and can add the command to the crontab of user1, you can do that also. That may be the best solution.

```
user1$ crontab -e
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I dont want to disable the password altogether but wanted to enter the password during sudo run-time. Is there a way? :(

Answer (score 0):

Either add a NOPASSWD option in `/etc/sudoers` as Igor says, or just schedule the command in *user2*'s crontab in the first place.