# Run python script in a remote machines as a sudo user

Tags: python, unix, sudo, remote-server

I pretty new to python programming, as part of my learning i had decided to start coding for a simple daily task which would save sometime, I'm done with most part of the script but now i see a big challenge in executing it , because i need to execute it a remote server with the sudo user access. Basically what i need is,

> login to remote system.
>   run sudo su - user(no need of password as its a SSH key based login)
>   run the code.
>   logout with the result assigned to varible.
>   I need the end result of the script stored in a variable so that i can use that back for verification.

Comment: you can't assign results to variable without other programs. You can only save it to file or database.

Comment: Have a look at ansible and similar.

Comment: Do you have sudo access on the remote machine?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105444/unix-run-a-command-as-another-user?rq=1) Using pexpect, should be able to do what you want.

Comment: [fabric.operations.run(*args, **kwargs)](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run) - Run a shell command on a remote host.

Comment: @cooper : I do have sudo access to remote machine. ill check how feasible is pexpect and get back to you on that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers guys.
Fabric worked for me, below is the code snippet.

```
from fabric.context_managers import settings
from fabric.api import *
with settings(host_string='username@host',user='runcommand_user'):
     run('command')
```

But before using this make sure you have set sudo access as below in the host
(runcommand_user) NOPASSWD: ALL

u can login into host and execute 'sudo -l' to check if you have the access as mentioned above

Comment: The other way is to use paramiko as below.  
un_con=paramiko.SSHClient()
un_con.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
un_con.connect(host,username=user,key_filename=keyfile)
stdin, stdout, stderr = un_con.exec_command(cmd)

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to use paramiko as below.

> *un_con=paramiko.SSHClient()
>   un_con.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>   un_con.connect(host,username=user,key_filename=keyfile) stdin, stdout,
>   stderr = un_con.exec_command(sudo -H -u sudo_user bash -c 'command')*